# Is your dodge / block chance reduced to zero if you have your back turned on an enemy? (ala WoW)

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

Should i be worried or concerned if i charge / leap INTO a room full of monsters or should i never leave my soft underbelly (behind) exposed?

Comment: As a wizard, my behind is exposed quite a bit (not literally) whenever tough enemies try to come near

Answer (score 17):

Just checked it in-game, stood in a corner and let mobs hit my back. I dodged and blocked attacks even though I was with my back to them. Now I dont know if the chance to block/dodge gets reduced, but certainly not to zero.

Added images.

Dodging
[image: dodging]

Blocking
[image: blocking]

Comment: Additionally, you can still dodge even when you are stunned or feared.

Comment: You also appear to be able to dodge/block while moving

Comment: Actually, my experience tells me, you have a higher chance to dodge while moving. Don't know if the same applies to blocking.